# Java: How to cleanly handle the absence of an external library?

Tags: java, external

I'm working with a commercial API Library that I do not have a license to distribute.

The end user of my application must have the library installed and in the classpath in order for my application to work.  Beyond the jar, they must also have some other files in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

I'd prefer to run a test on start up that the pre-requisites are installed and the objects I'm using work properly.  If not, return a user friendly message with instructions or perform some sort of correction.  (like asking the user where the libraries are installed and writing some variables into the startup script).

I have found [ClassLoader.loadClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) and I think I should be using this, but I haven't been able to find an example that spells out my use case and I'm not sure if it's OK to use that directly.

I believe that if loadClass succeeds, I need to instantiate a class object and try using it to determine if the LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set correctly.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: @AlexWien - As it turns out, `ClassNotFoundException` can't be caught like that.  I had put off actually implementing/testing it until earlier today.  I'm working on a solution, and when I am clear on it I will post it, but I'm in a bit of a quagmire of classpath bugs that are unrelated so it might take a day or two.

Comment: ok, interesting, i dont see any reasons why it should not work, maybe you can later explain.

Comment: Apparently `ClassNotFoundException` is a checked exception that has to be declared, otherwise you get a compile-time error.  When java can't find a class at runtime, it throws an error and not an exception, so a generic try/catch (Exception e) doesn't work either.  But... Error and Exception both derive from Throwable so you can have a generic try/catch (Throwable e) which catches NoClass and any other errors.

Comment: ok, can you check the throwable with instanceof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a method that throws an Exception, inside that you can catch `ClassNotFoundException` or `NoClassDefFoundError`

```
        public void testCatchException() {
            try {
                checkClassesExisting();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                // TODO handle exception
            } catch (NoClassDefFoundError ex) {
                // TODO handle exception
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // other error
            }
        }


        public void checkClassesExisting() throws Exception {
            // instantiate here the class in doubt
            Dummy = new Dummy("xx");
        }
```

Addidional Info at [NoClassDefFoundError](http://javafanatics.blogspot.de/2007/03/noclassdeffounderror-vs.html)

Comment: And here I was trying to make things more complicated for myself.  Thanks for making things easy on me.

Comment: As it turns out, you cannot try/catch a `ClassNotFoundException`.  If you do, you'll receive this error: `Unreachable catch block for ClassNotFoundException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body`.  What you can do is try/catch a Throwable, but since that could be another kind of error, so you have to check the Throwable for getClass().getName().equals("java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError") and handle that appropriately/different than any other exceptions or errors that could arise from your constructor.

Comment: ok, feel free to update my answer with the working solution, or post a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to require the 3rd party library to be purchased in order to use yours, you shouldn't really do anything.  Let the ClassNotFoundException come up to the top.  The exception will tell you which library is missing.

If you do catch the ClassNotFoundException and you have a configuration problem with a class in your library, it will be masked by what you think is this missing 3rd party library.

Comment: I do want to let the user know what the problem is, but I'd prefer to provide an error message they will understand better.  NoClassDefFoundError doesn't mean anything to my end users.      
  
"The XX API has not been found.  Please see docs/apierrors.pdf for a solution to this problem" would be a lot more helpful.

Comment: Well at least make sure to add the original exception as the cause (usually the second argument to exceptions) so it has full visibility...

Answer (score 1):

For finding if a jar is available, I would use `Class.forName` for trying to load a class from that jar.

If the native libraries are initialized / checked in static blocks in the classes wrapping them, the same method should work for them too.